# Priority Queue Constructors Java

Tags: java

I am currently having a difficulty understanding the role of a constructor when it comes to a Priority Queue. I have gone through and created methods such as peek, pop, length and etc for the queue however I am stuck to when it comes to the constructor. It is probably a mental block more than anything.

My class is as follows:

```
public class PQueue<T> {

private PQueueItem<T> head;

public static enum ORDER {
    ASC, DESC;
}

public static ORDER DEFAULT_ORDER;
private ORDER order;

/**
 * The default constructor for a PQueue, with the default order for priorities
 */
public PQueue() {
    // ...add code
}

/**
 * The constructor to make a new PQueue with a given order
 * 
 * @param order
 */
public PQueue(ORDER order) {
    // ...add code
}

/**
 * Remove and return data from the item at the front of the queue
 * 
 * @return
 */
public T pop() {

    if(head == null) {
        return null;
    }
        // temp variable to hold head data
        T e1 = head.getData();
        // gives the next item the head
        head = head.getNext();
        // returns temp variable
        return e1;
}

/**
 * Return the data from the item at the front of the queue, without removing the
 * item itself
 * 
 * @return
 */
public T peek() {
    // returns head data
    if(head == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return head.getData();
}

/**
 * Remove and return the item at the front of the queue
 * 
 * @return
 */
public PQueueItem<T> popItem() {
    if (head == null) {
        return null;
    }
    // temp variable to hold item
    PQueueItem<T> e1 = this.head;
    // gives the next item the head
    this.head = head.getNext();
    // returns temp variable
    return e1;
}

/**
 * Return the item at the front of the queue without removing it
 * 
 * @return
 */
public PQueueItem<T> peekItem() {
    if (head == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return head;
}

/**
 * Insert a new item into the queue, which should be put in the right place
 * according to its priority. That is, is order == ASC, then the new item should
 * appear in the queue before all items with a HIGHER priority. If order ==
 * DESC, then the new item should appear in the queue before all items with a
 * LOWER priority.
 * 
 * @param data
 * @param priority
 */

public void insert(T data, int priority) {
    if (order == ORDER.ASC) {
        // current item
        PQueueItem<T> e1 = head;

        while (e1.getNext() != null) {

            // is inserted item greater than current item
            if (priority > e1.getPriority()) {

                // is inserted item smaller than next item
                if (priority < e1.getNext().getPriority()) {

                    // create and insert new item, reassign links in the list
                    PQueueItem<T> newPQ = new PQueueItem<T>(data, priority);
                    newPQ.setNext(e1.getNext());
                    e1.setNext(newPQ);
                }

                // check to see if priority equates to the next item's priority
                else if (priority == e1.getNext().getPriority()) {

                    // is new item's data alphabetically greater than the next item's data
                    if (((String) data).compareToIgnoreCase((String) e1.getNext().getData()) > 0) {
                        PQueueItem<T> nextPQ = e1.getNext();
                        PQueueItem<T> newPQ = new PQueueItem<T>(data, priority);
                        newPQ.setNext(nextPQ.getNext());
                        nextPQ.setNext(newPQ);
                    } else {
                        PQueueItem<T> newPQ = new PQueueItem<T>(data, priority);
                        newPQ.setNext(e1.getNext());
                        e1.setNext(newPQ);
                    }
                } else {

                    // iterate current item
                    e1 = head.getNext();
                }
            }

            // if item to be inserted is smaller than the current item
            else if (priority < e1.getPriority()) {
                PQueueItem<T> newPQ = new PQueueItem<T>(e1.getData(), e1.getPriority());
                newPQ.setNext(e1.getNext());
                e1.setData(data);
                e1.setPriority(priority);
            }
        }
    } else if (order == ORDER.DESC) {
        PQueueItem<T> e1 = head;
        while (e1.getNext() != null) {

            // is inserted item less than current item
            if (priority < e1.getPriority()) {

                // is inserted item greater than next item
                if (priority > e1.getNext().getPriority()) {

                    // create and insert new item, reassign links in the list
                    PQueueItem<T> newPQ = new PQueueItem<T>(data, priority);
                    newPQ.setNext(e1.getNext());
                    e1.setNext(newPQ);
                }

                // check to see if priority equates to the next item's priority
                else if (priority == e1.getNext().getPriority()) {

                    // is new item's data alphabetically less than the next item's data
                    if (((String) data).compareToIgnoreCase((String) e1.getNext().getData()) < 0) {
                        PQueueItem<T> nextPQ = e1.getNext();
                        PQueueItem<T> newPQ = new PQueueItem<T>(data, priority);
                        newPQ.setNext(nextPQ.getNext());
                        nextPQ.setNext(newPQ);
                    } else {
                        PQueueItem<T> newPQ = new PQueueItem<T>(data, priority);
                        newPQ.setNext(e1.getNext());
                        e1.setNext(newPQ);
                    }
                } else {

                    // iterate current item
                    e1 = head.getNext();
                }
            }

            // if item to be inserted is greater than the current item
            else if (priority > e1.getPriority()) {
                PQueueItem<T> newPQ = new PQueueItem<T>(e1.getData(), e1.getPriority());
                newPQ.setNext(e1.getNext());
                e1.setData(data);
                e1.setPriority(priority);
            }
        }

    }
}

/**
 * Return the length of the queue
 * 
 * @return
 */
public int length() {
    if (head == null) {
        return 0;
    } else {
    int size = 0;
    for (PQueueItem<T> i = head; i.getNext() != null; i = i.getNext()) {
        size++;
    }
    return size;
}
}

public String toString() {
    int i = length();
    PQueueItem<T> current = head;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (i > 0) {
        sb.append(current.toString());
        if (i > 1)
            sb.append(": ");
        current = current.getNext();
        i--;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

}
```

Also when it comes to the code I have done a few null checks however I have read that there is a method of using optional which is far cleaner and better. If you have any recommendations can you please let me know?

The other class for the PQueueItem is as below:

```
public class PQueueItem<T> {

private int priority;
private T data;
private PQueueItem<T> next;

public PQueueItem(T data, int priority) {
    this.data = data;
    this.priority = priority;
}
public int getPriority() {
    return priority;
}
public void setPriority(int priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}
public T getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
}
public PQueueItem<T> getNext() {
    return next;
}
public void setNext(PQueueItem<T> next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public String toString() {
    return String.format("[%s,%d]", data.toString(), priority);
}

}
```

Thank you in advanced and any criticism will be taken with gratitude.

Comment: What do you need to execute your algorithms? Set it in your constructor.

Comment: You wrote all that code, yet don't know what to put in the constructor?

Comment: The task gives us the method and etc and there is a test file that we use for testing.

Comment: I have a hard time believing you wrote any of that (or was `insert()` provided for you?). Why is `DEFAULT_ORDER` not initialized?

Comment: The base code is provided to us. We just need to fill out the methods.